# Explode function

Tags: python, json, pandas, pandas-explode

This is my first question on here. I have searched around on here and throughout the web and I seem unable to find the answer to my question. I'm trying to explode out a list in a json file out into multiple columns and rows. Everything I have tried so far has proven unsuccessful.

I am doing this over multiple json files within a directory in order to have it print out in the dataframe like this.
Goal:

| did | Version | Nodes | rds | time | c | sc | f | uc |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| did | Version | Nodes | rds | time | c | sc | f | uc |
| did | Version | Nodes | rds | time | c | sc | f | uc |
| did | Version | Nodes | rds | time | c | sc | f | uc |

Instead I get this in my dataframe:

| did | Version | Nodes | rds | fusage |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| did | Version | Nodes | rds | everything in fusage |
| did | Version | Nodes | rds | everything in fusage |
| did | Version | Nodes | rds | everything in fusage |

example of the json I'm working with. The json structure will not change

```
{
  "did": "123456789",
  "mId": "1a2b3cjsks",
  "timestamp": "2021-11-26T11:10:58.322000",
  "beat": {
    "did": "123456789",
    "collectionTime": "2010-05-26 11:10:58.004783+00",
    "Nodes": 6,
    "Version": "v1.4.6-2",
    "rds": "0.00B",
    "fusage": [
      {
        "time": "2010-05-25",
        "c": "string",
        "sc": "string",
        "f": "string",
        "uc": "int"
      },
      {
        "time": "2010-05-19",
        "c": "string",
        "sc": "string",
        "f": "string",
        "uc": "int"
      },
      {
        "t": "2010-05-23",
        "c": "string",
        "sc": "string",
        "f": "string",
        "uc": "int"
      },
      {
        "time": "2010-05-23",
        "c": "string",
        "sc": "string",
        "f": "string",
        "uc": "int"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

My end goal is to get the dataframe out to a csv in order to be ingested. I appreciate everyone's help looking at this.

using python 3.8.10 & pandas 1.3.4

python code below

```
import csv
import glob
import json
import os
import pandas as pd

tempdir = '/dir/to/files/json_temp'
json_files = os.path.join(tempdir, '*.json')
file_list = glob.glob(json_files)
dfs = []

for file in file_list:
    with open(file) as f:
        data = pd.json_normalize(json.loads(f.read()))
        dfs.append(data)
        df = pd.concat(dfs, ignore_index=True)
        df.explode('fusage')
        print(df)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're going to use the explode function, after that, apply `pd.Series` over the column containing the `fusage` list (`beat.fusage`) to obtain a Series for each list item.

```
/dir/to/files
├── example-v1.4.6-2.json
└── example-v2.2.2-2.json
```

```py
...
for file in file_list:
    with open(file) as f:
        data = pd.json_normalize(json.loads(f.read()))
        dfs.append(data)

df = pd.concat(dfs, ignore_index=True)
fusage_list = df.explode('beat.fusage')['beat.fusage'].apply(pd.Series)
df = pd.concat([df, fusage_list], axis=1)

# show desired columns
df = df[['did', 'beat.Version', 'beat.Nodes', 'beat.rds', 'time', 'c', 'sc', 'f', 'uc']]
print(df)
```

Output from *df*

```py
         did beat.Version  beat.Nodes beat.rds        time       c      sc       f   uc
0  123456789     v1.4.6-2           6    0.00B  2010-05-25  string  string  string  int
0  123456789     v1.4.6-2           6    0.00B  2010-05-19  string  string  string  int
0  123456789     v1.4.6-2           6    0.00B         NaN  string  string  string  int
0  123456789     v1.4.6-2           6    0.00B  2010-05-23  string  string  string  int
1  123777777     v2.2.2-2           4    0.00B  2010-05-25  string  string  string  int
1  123777777     v2.2.2-2           4    0.00B  2010-05-19  string  string  string  int
1  123777777     v2.2.2-2           4    0.00B         NaN  string  string  string  int
1  123777777     v2.2.2-2           4    0.00B  2010-05-23  string  string  string  int
```

Comment: Thanks for your assistance. I appreciate it!